# Can't use advanced custom fields value from Wordpress

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, swift, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use values from my Wordpress server in my Swift project. I get the information in JSON format. The values that I want is created by "advanced custom fields" on the wordpress server.

I am loading it from another view controller and use this code to load it:

```
let nummer = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("nummer")
print(nummer)
```

Then I get this result:

```
{
    attachments =     (
    );
    author =     {
        description = "";
        "first_name" = "";
        id = 1;
        "last_name" = "";
        name = admin;
        nickname = admin;
        slug = admin;
        url = "";
    };
    categories =     (
    );
    "comment_count" = 0;
    "comment_status" = open;
    comments =     (
    );
    content = "<p>text</p>\n";
    "custom_fields" =     {
        latitude =         (
            "22.324432"
        );
        longitude =         (
            "40.233221"
        );
    };
    date = "2015-12-11 08:12:31";
    excerpt = "<p>text</p>\n";
    id = 37;
    modified = "2015-12-11 08:12:31";
    slug = "test-2";
    status = publish;
    tags =     (
    );
    title = test;
    "title_plain" = test;
    type = post;
    url = "http://localhost:8080/wordpress/2015/12/11/test-2/";
}
```

To get the title I use this code:

```
let dict = nummer!["title"] as? String
print(dict)
```

And get this result:
**Optional("test")**

I use this code to get longitude value:

```
let dict = nummer!["custom_fields"]
let longitude = dict!!["longitude"]
print(longitude)
```

Result:
**Optional((
    "40.233221"
))**

Now I want to convert it to a double. But it returns nil:

```
let longitude = dict!!["longitude"] as? Double
print(longitude)
```

Result: **nil**

Why does it returns nil and not the double value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `as?` you are attempting to downcast the unwrapped value to a `Double`, but it isn't a `Double` it's an `Array`.

```
if let longitudeArray = dict!!["longitude"] as? Array<String> {
    if let longitude = Double(longitudeArray[0]) {
        print(longitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, and then I'm using print(longitude) after it. But nothing happens.

Comment: Interesting.  It seems you don't have a String then in `dict!!["longitude"]`.  If you set a breakpoint after this line `let longitude = dict!!["longitude"]` what type does it say `longitude` is in the debugger?

Comment: I get this result: (AnyObject?!) $R0 = Some {
  instance_type = 0x00007fb62350a380 -> 0x00000001066e2ae0 (void *)0x00000001066e2b08: __NSCFArray
}

Comment: Hey @MatKoffman, I reproduced your data and had a play.  Try that edit above.  It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because this variable is a `String` not `Double`. You have to convert it

```
if let longitudeString = dict!!["longitude"] as? String {
    let longitude = Double(longitudeString)
}
```

or

```
if let longitudeString = dict!!["longitude"] as? String {
    let longitude = longitudeString.doubleValue
}
```

Comment: I believe your second one would require you to downcast to `NSString`, not `String`.  Best to use the first anyway.

Comment: I tried both of them, and then I use print(longitude) but it doesn't print anything.